# visual studio code cant be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, osx-elcapitan

I have OS X El Capitan, and after i downloaded VS Code, I tried to open VS Code and i am getting this error:

visual studio code cant be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed

Screen shot of the error message:

[image]

I have latest OS X El Capitan and i tried few times to open VS code with no luck.

Any recommendation how to fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

This issue is related to tight signing contrasting on OS X El Capitan, Here is how to fix this issue:

To fix this follow these steps:

1) Open System Preferences.

2) Double click on Security & Privacy.

3) Under General Tab, click on Advanced.

4) Change the settings to: Allow apps downloaded from Anywhere.

[image]

5) Close the window, Open Visual Studio Code.

VS Code opens for the first time with no issues.

6) Go back to the same window as mentioned in step 3, change the option as it was before: Mac App Store and identified developers.

7) Re-open VS Code and it will open with no issues.

Comment: What happens after I do this and I want to set "Allow apps downloaded from Anywhere" back?

Comment: @Devian1 you can set this option "Anywhere", but it is risky. you are opening your OS for any vendor who is not identified. If you want to set "Anywhere" option,VS works with no issues as well.

Comment: In El Capitan (Security & Privacy -> General -> Advanced), it listed Visual Studio as "attempted to open", but has a button next to it labeled "Open Anyway." Click that and it will then open VS, no need to change the "Anywhere" setting.

Answer (score 3):

A better answer would be not to change system preferences, but you can open by right clicking (or control+click) application, then pressing open (You'll have to view it from finder view or on desktop). Mac's default to not allowing unknown developers to one click open.

Answer (score 2):

Our next release 0.9.0 will have a fix for this problem. We plan to ship it next week!

Comment: Thanks for the update Ben! appreciate it. looking forward to it. I will write a blog about this fix when it is released.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System preferences, security, privacy and then move to General tab to allow  the access to *vscode developer*, It works for new *macos* version catalina.

Answer (score 0):

try removing External attribute  "com.apple.quarantine". it will work

xattr -d

drwxr-xr-x**@**  3 maca  staff     96 Aug 30 15:50 Visual Studio Code.app